# Duplicate Namespaces in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, namespaces, php-5.3

I'm new to namespaces and curious whether it's possible for there to be duplicates. For example, I'm working in a Wordpress environment using a popular script in my plugin. This plugin uses a namespace. If other plugins are also using this same script with the same namespace, will they clash because of the duplicate namespace?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no such thing as duplicate namespaces.  There will be clashes if there are two _classes_ within a given namespace that have the same name.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the heads up. I'm still trying to wrap my head around them in general and knowing there just can't be duplicate namespaces helps. Thanks again :)

Comment: No prob, they're a pretty abstract concept.  All they are useful for is creating a 'space' of your own where you can name something anything you want, without having to worry about whether that class name has already been taken.

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces should be unique identifiers.

```
namespace XmlComponents; class XmlWriter{ } etc..

namespace XmlComponents; class XmlReader { } etc..

use XmlComponents as foo
```

PHP - 'Who is foo'?

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces should be unique.

Yes, they should, but according to the PHP manual "the same namespace may be defined in multiple files"....

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php